# az acr command working fine in bash run but not in pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-container-registry

I am running below command from bash command line (Ubuntu subsystem)

```
az acr import --username AAAA --password AAAA --name AAAA --source "AAAA/AAAA:AAA" --image "AAAA:AAA"
```

If I use the same in Azure pipeline but getting below error

> ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to edit your question to add your code inside `code` and also have the error on a blockquote for example. As the error suggests you are not logged in with az into a subscription. You could perform this action using the nested az task for Azure Devops `AzureCLI@2` which will request from you an ARM service connection

Answer (score 1):

Unlike manually executing the Azure CLI commands locally, in Azure Pipelines, you need to use the specific [**Azure CLI task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) to execute the Azure CLI commands.

Below are the things you need to do:

1. Create an [**Azure Resource Manager service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection) (ARM connection) that can connect to the Azure subscription and Source Group where the ACR are in.
2. In the pipeline, add the **Azure CLI task**.

   - Select the ARM connection created in previous step as the value of **Azure Resource Manager connection** field. The task will use the ARM connection as the authentication to access the ACR.
   - Select **Shell** as the value of **Script Type** field.
   - Add Azure CLI commands as the **Inline Script** on the task.

     If the source registry is ACR, you can try with the following command.

     ```sh
     az acr import --name AAAA --source "AAAA/AAAA:AAA" --image "AAAA:AAA"
     ```

     If the source registry is outside Azure, you can try with the following command.

     ```sh
     az acr import --username AAAA --password AAAA --name AAAA --source "AAAA/AAAA:AAA" --image "AAAA:AAA"
     ```

[image]